# How to create sub resource in restlet

Tags: rest, restlet, restlet-2.3.1

How to create a sub resource in restlet

1- I want to have two @Get annotated method in same resource
2- I want to assign each method a URI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, this can only be done using the JAX-RS support of Restlet. For the native REST support (classes that extend `ServerResource`) they can be attached to a single path. I mean every annotated methods in the server resource will be called on the same path.

That said you can define several `@Get` methods in a same server resource but the routing will be done based on media types or query parameters.

Hope it answers your question.
Thierry

Comment: Thanks @Thierry Done using query Param